# TSQL with SSIS CHAR(13) and CHAR(10) question: The CHAR(13) seems to be missing

Tags: t-sql, ssis, formatting

I'm building a SQL job with a dynamic query, something like:

```
DECLARE @command nvarchar(max);

--Real command is a bit longer :)
SET @command = N'SELECT
    [A] = N''' + DB_NAME() + '''
    ,[B] = N''' + @@SERVERNAME + ''';';

--EXEC [msdb].dbo.sp_add_job command
--EXEC [msdb].dbo.sp_add_jobstep
--    stuff
--    ,@subsystem = N'TSQL'
--    ,@command = @command
```

This works fine. when I run this query from the SSMS I get a nice formated jobstep when I look at the SQL jobstep properties:

```
SELECT
    [A] = N'Foo'
    ,[B] = N'Bar';
```

However when I paste the dynamic query in an TSQL task in SSIS and execute the task in SSIS I get a ugly one liner:

```
SELECT [A] = N'Foo', [B] = N'Bar';
```

When I look at the query in the [msdb].dbo.[sysjobsteps] it seems that the CHAR(13) are missing from the SQL query.

```
SELECT
    [LF] = CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), [command], 1)
    ,[CR] = CHARINDEX(CHAR(13), [command], 1)
FROM [msdb].dbo.[sysjobsteps]
WHERE [subsystem] = N'TSQL'
AND [job_id] = <myjob>;

/*
LF CR
-- --
7  0

Expecting:
LF CR
-- --
8  7
*/
```

If I then update the command string in [msdb].dbo.[sysjobsteps] the formating is okay again in the jobstep properties:

```
UPDATE a
SET [command] = REPLACE([command], CHAR(10), CHAR(13) + CHAR(10))
FROM [msdb].dbo.[sysjobsteps] a
WHERE [subsystem] = N'TSQL'
AND [job_id] = <myjob>;
```

So I know that the jobstep properties expects a CR and LF and doesn't like the LF.

Somewhere along the way the Execute SQL task removes the CHAR(13), any ideas on how I can get SSIS to not remove the CHAR(13)?

Comment: I don't understand what you're actually asking here. if you copy something with line breaks, it'll have line breaks when you paste it; unless you're copying from an SSMS cell and you haven't turned on retain line breaks and carriage returns? *"However when I paste this query in an TSQL task in SSIS"* Where are you copying the data from?

Comment: Hi Larnu, I'm writing the code in SSMS so I can test it and such, when I execute it in SSMS the query the jobstep property window has nice CR and LFs. When I copy the query to generate the jobstep from SSMS (so NOT from the resultpane but from the query design pane) into a "Execute SQL task" in a SSIS package and execute the task the CR's are missing in the query the jobstep property window, and the query looks like a one liner.

Comment: Found the cause, dtsx packages are stored as an XML stream, when I look at the stream I can see the &#xA; (LF) but I'm missing the &#xD; (CR).
Anyways to have SSIS use &#xD; en &#xA; as a line break?

Answer (score 0):

Found way to fix it, I added this:

```
IF CHARINDEX(CHAR(13), @command, 1) = 0
    SET @Command = REPLACE(@Command, CHAR(10), CHAR(13) + CHAR(10));
```

This fixes the missing CHAR(13) when running from a SSIS package.